# Why "Program timed out after 5 seconds" happens in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm doing assembly debugging with gdb for my school homework. The problem is that the program runs only once in gdb. After then, whenever I try it just prints "Program timed out after 5 seconds" and won't run again.

So what I do is run `~/Desktop/lab/ $ gdb filename` > `(gdb) run` > (debug) > `(gdb) quit` > run `gdb filename`... again and again. This makes me spend twice of the time and annoys me a lot. Does gdb originally run once? or will there be a way to fix it? Please help me.

Thank you.

```
(gdb) run -u 2014-14459       //the program runs for the first time
Starting program: /home/devel/Desktop/lab/seokyoung-kook/buflab-handout/bufbomb -u 2014-14459
Userid: 2014-14459
Cookie: 0x3beba64f

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048db0 in getbuf ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function getbuf,
which has no line number information.
Program timed out after 5 seconds
Type string:[Inferior 1 (process 2794) exited with code 01]
(gdb) s
The program is not being run.
(gdb) s
The program is not being run.
(gdb) run -u 2014-14459                     //second try
Starting program: /home/devel/Desktop/lab/seokyoung-kook/buflab-handout/bufbomb -u 2014-14459
Userid: 2014-14459
Cookie: 0x3beba64f
Program timed out after 5 seconds           //not running
Type string:[Inferior 1 (process 2797) exited with code 01]
(gdb) run -u 2014-14459                     //third try
Starting program: /home/devel/Desktop/lab/seokyoung-kook/buflab-handout/bufbomb -u 2014-14459
Userid: 2014-14459
Cookie: 0x3beba64f
Program timed out after 5 seconds           //not running
Type string:[Inferior 1 (process 2798) exited with code 01]
(gdb) s
The program is not being run.
```

Comment: Which gdb version do you use?

Comment: I guess that's not a gdb message. Probably the program itself has a built-in timer.

Comment: Your "bomb" is tamper-proof :P  It looks like it's intentionally making it difficult to single-step, maybe because you're "supposed" to reverse engineer it just from disassembly.  Or maybe to stop you from modifying registers with a debugger instead of finding the right disarming input?

Comment: @fuz it is GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.10.1 vanilla) 7.10.1

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh yes the file is given as executable file, not the source code. to do the reverse engineering line by line in assembly, should I use another command than `s`?

Comment: Use `objdump -d` to disassemble your binary, only using a debugger for single-stepping or a breakpoint if you need to check a register value for a specific instruction or something.  (Or Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler is very nice for reversing because it marks branch targets in the disassembly, making it easier to find basic block boundaries.  https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv)

Comment: Or you could use `strace` to find out how the process is killing itself, e.g. probably with `alarm(3)` and a SIGALRM signal handler.  You could use GDB to skip that part of the program's startup, or maybe set SIGALRM to SIG_IGN (ignored) by using GDB to make system calls in the context of the process.  I forget, maybe you can write a wrapper for the program that execve's it with that signal set to ignore.  But since the program probably installs its own signal handler, the default disposition of SIGALRM probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the kind answer! It helped me a lot. I shall also try objconv... Thank you again :)